# Duplicate column in right

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have the following problem: I want to duplicate the content from the left side to the right side in a new column. Can someone help me?

now it looks like this: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBtoY.png)

```
<footer class="contacts_wrap scheme_<?php echo esc_attr(fivestars_get_custom_option('contacts_scheme')); ?>">
                    <div class="contacts_wrap_inner">
                        <div class="content_wrap">
                        <div class="columns_wrap sc_columns columns_nofluid sc_columns_count_4">
                            <div class="column-3_4 sc_column_item sc_column_item_1 odd first span_2">
                            <?php
                        echo ((!empty($address_1) || !empty($address_2)) ? '<i class="icon trx-icon icon-location"></i>' : '')
                            . (!empty($address_1) ? '<span class="address1">' . esc_html($address_1) . '</span>' : '')
                            . ((!empty($address_1) && !empty($address_2)) ? ', ' : '')
                            . (!empty($address_2) ? '<span class="address2">' . esc_html($address_2) . '</span>' : '' ); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column-3_4 sc_column_item sc_column_item_3 odd after_span_2">
                                <?php if (!empty($phone)) echo '<i class="icon trx-icon icon-phone-1"></i>' . esc_html($phone); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column-3_4 sc_column_item sc_column_item_4 even" style="padding: 0;">
                                <?php if (!empty($email)) echo '<i class="icon trx-icon icon-mail-empty"></i><span class="address2">' . esc_html($email) . '</span>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>     
              

              
                    </div>  <!-- /.contacts_wrap_inner -->
                </footer>   <!-- /.contacts_wrap -->
```

I tried to create a new div, to display it on the right side, but it didn't work.
I expect the content from the left column to be present on the right as well.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVGGm.png)